# Identify the type of .net applicaiton using web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently got a job wherein I have to maintain and enhance an already existing .net application.  I am asked to change the web app layout and also the code quality.

I am lost on what sort of web application I am given to work on.  The application has a bunch of .aspx files with corresponding .cs and .designer.cs files.  I am pasting a few lines from web.config which I think might be relevant.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="oleDbProvider" value="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"/>
    <add key="excelVersion" value="Excel 8.0"/>
  </appSettings>
.
.
.
.
.
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
.
.
.
.
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

I want to find out the type of .net application this is and then add MVC framework so that I can start writing REST Apis.

Comment: looks like it maybe webforms app

Answer (score 1):

The project you are describing is a ASP.NET Web Forms application. (.NET Version: 3.5)

Some giveaways are:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"....
```

My suggestion is this:

DO NOT update the project to fit MVC. You can use the same solution, but you cannot mix Web Forms and MVC very easily in the same project, if at all.

I would create another project in the solution. MVC and Web Forms are architecturally very different. You can use the same classes if they do not directly reference any of the classes or functionality that is specfic to either one.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC